# Question about countable and uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

13. Consider the following sets:
    i. $Y_1 = ∅$
    ii. $Y_2 = P(Y_1)$
    iii. $Y = \{Y_1, Y_2\}$
    iv. $Z × Z ∪ Q$
    v. $N.$
    vi. R
    vii. ${f : \{0, 1\} → R}$
    viii. Set of relations on $N$.
    ix. $R × R$
    x. $R × Q$.
    xi. $\{0, 1\}^N$
    xii. $N^{\{0,1\}}$

a) Which sets above are finite?
b) For the sets which are finite, order then by ascending cardinality.
c) Which sets above are countable?
d) Which sets above are countably infinite?
e) Which sets above are uncountable?
f) Which sets have cardinality greater than c = |R|?

a) i,ii,iii are finite and they are arranged in ascending order
c)if they are finite then they are countable, so i,ii,iii are countable.
d)iv is countable infinite because the union of two infinite countable sets is infinite countable. v is C.I. viii is countable because it will be set of all ordered pairs of the cartesian product of natural numbers. I have no idea how XI and XII work.

e) VI is uncountable by cantor's diagonalization. VIII, VIV,X ARE U.C (by intuition).

f) I don't know how to do this one and I need help with XI and XII

An explanation for the ones I am doing by intuition would be helpful. Cite a source if it's necessary. I am just making use of the fact the union of countable is countable, the union of uncountable is uncountable and the union of countable and uncountable is uncountable

Comment: hint for xi: binary representation of reals

Comment: and that's for?

Comment: you know the size of reals. so you know something about the minimal size of the representation (sequence of digits) of the reals in any number system (decimal, binary,...)

Comment: viii is not the set of all ordered pairs; it is the set of all _subsets_ of the set of ordered pairs (because a relation is a set of ordered pars, i.e. a subset of the set of ordered pairs).

Comment: Right tony. xi and xii are countable infinite right?.

Comment: xi is not countable since the reals are not - each real has a representation as sequence of digits in the binary system (in analogy to our decimal system). your set is the set of all such sequences. xii is countable since its the naturals squared, thats right.

Comment: reals?. What does this notation represent $\{0,1\}^{\{N\}}$. I thought it is like $\{0^1,0^2,.......\}$ or $\{1^1,1^2,.......\}$

Comment: infinite series of $0$s and $1$s: $\left\{\left(0,0,0,....\right), \left(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,......\right), \text{and many many more} \right\}$

Comment: I don't know how you relate those numbers to the reals. There is no bijection with the naturals by intuition, so it's uncountable. I don'w know how you relate them to the reals. It's that every real has a binary representation, but I don't if the strings take into account decimals.We would need something like 1111.1111

Comment: the bijection (actually its a surjection onto the interval $\left[0,1\right]$ but for the moment this is enough) is $\left\{0,1\right\}^{\mathbb{N}}\ni(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mapsto\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\cdot 2^{-n}$

Comment: what about this set $N^{\{0,1\}}$.

Comment: countable by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#/media/File:Pairing_natural.svg (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)

Comment: yeah, but how do you describe one element.

Comment: pairs of naturals

Comment: XD how did you know so it's every $(a,b) \in N \times N$